# how can i fix image src

Tags: html, pug

When I use this code, it's right : 
`img(src="http://localhost:3030/uploads/customerimages/42.jpg", alt="image")`

but this code gives 404 error : 
`img(src="./uploads/customerimages/42.jpg", alt="image")`.

The second one output is http://localhost:3050/information/edit/uploads/customerimages/42.jpg

but need http://localhost:3030/uploads/customerimages/42.jpg.

http://localhost:3050/information/edit is current route.

How can i solve this?

Comment: The `./` is Directory traversal remove the `./`.

Comment: make sure the directory where you are looking for the image is in the public directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove dot before `url`
Use like

```
img(src="/uploads/customerimages/42.jpg", alt="image")
```